# Integral of the form $\frac{dx}{(ax^2 + bx + c)\sqrt{px +q}}$

Tags: integration

As the title suggests, I want to evaluate: $\int \frac{dx}{(ax^2 + bx + c)\sqrt{px +q}}$ given $a,p \neq 0$.

I tried the substitution $px + q = t^2$, which yields:
 $ \int \frac{dt}{(At^4 + Bt^2 + C)}$ where $A,B,C$ are some constants such that $A \neq 0$. How do I solve this new integral, or is there an easier substitution?

($A = \frac{a}{p^2} $,
$B = \frac{bp - 2aq}{p^2} $ and
$C = \frac{aq^2 - bpq + cp^2}{p^2} $)

Comment: Isn’t that good enough? :)

Comment: it's ugly but you just apply partial fraction decomposition from here

Comment: I don't know how to solve the integral $\int \frac{dt}{At^4 + Bt^2 + C} $. For a partial fraction decomposition, I would need to factorize it, how to do that?

Comment: Find the roots, treat it as a quadratic in $t^2$.

Comment: But what if it is an irreducible polynomial in $t^2$ i.e. no real roots?

Comment: You can still do partial fraction expansion with complex roots. Not quite sure I see how you did that substitution in the general case though.

Comment: But if I use complex numbers, then the final answer will also be in terms of $i$, is there a way to avoid that i.e. get an answer only in terms of real coefficients? (And the substitution $px + q = t^2 \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{\sqrt{px + q}} = \frac{2}{p} dt$ and putting $x = \frac{t^2 - q}{p}$ in  $ax^2 + bx + c$ gives a quadratic in $t^2$.)

Comment: In fact, if the original quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c$ is irreducible, then so is $At^4 + Bt^2 + C$ as the discriminant of the latter quadratic in $t^2$ is $\frac{b^2 - 4ac}{p^2}$.